# Using multiple activities coherently

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

My application is based on estimating the cost of home renovation jobs such as decorating, taking user input in number format and processing it with formulas in order to provide the most accurate cost of materials, labor, etc. I am then displaying the results in a Text View and giving the option for exporting as a .csv file. Please see the picture attached below.

How do I add another activity, which does **exactly the same** job but retains the state of the previous activity? In other words, I want to *allow the user to estimate multiple hallways* and then concatenate the results into ONE total sum of costs in a separate activity.

I have tried to create another activity using the same layout but the data entered in the previous activity was destroyed so it proved no use. *I need to have multiple activities communicating with each other while retaining their instance state.* I hope that makes sense?

[Estimation app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y31wm.jpg)

Comment: Please add some code details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Instead of multiple Activities, you can consider multiple Fragments hosted within a single Activity instead, maybe managed by something like a ViewPager.  You can then have something like a common ViewModel tied to the Activity that collects and persists the information from all of those Fragments.